# How to create a searchlight in Unity ?

Tags: unity, lighting

I'm trying to create a WW2 simple game and I'm experience issue creating the light emitted from a Flak Searchlight.

The final lighting effect will be something like this:

http://s1115.photobucket.com/user/k4kittycrew/media/K4KITTY3/Slide2_zpsfccf1590.jpg.html

I know that it is called "volumetric light" and this is not supported by Unity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you're trying to achieve (eg. will the player see it up close or only in the distance like that?) it may be best to fake it by having a stretched quad shooting out from the light, with a semi-transparent texture of the light glow.